# NVMe or eMMC as host for my OS on ARM?

Tags: ssd, storage, nvme, arm, nvidia

I am working with the [Jetson AGX Xavier](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-agx-xavier-developer-kit) from NVIDIA. When flashing I get the option *Storage Device* to use the internal SD card (eMMC) or an SSD inserted into the M.2 connector (NVMe)

Both works fine for me since I am inserting an SSD anyway.
Can anyone explain to me which solution I should go for and why; I hate to choose the non-optimal choice and realize that after half a year.

If one option is not objectively better than the other, please share your experiences over opinions. And is helpful if your opinion is backed up with facts and references.

Comment: NVMe drives are a lot faster than eMMC. Whether this is an important factor for you or not it's up to you to decide.

Comment: Good point, thank you!

The eMMC is an internal storage, while the NVMe is mounted in the OS.
Any risk of running OS on a mounted device, rather than the internal hardware storage?

Comment: I think there's no problem but different OSes behave differently.